# jwysiwyg call a toolbar click programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, jwysiwyg

I am using [jwysiwyg](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg) and I would like to be able to click some of the toolbar buttons such as bold, italic, etc programmatically.  Is this possible?

Basically, I want something like this:

```
$('#editor').wysiwyg('click', 'bold');
```

Comment: If they don't offer a way to do it via their API, you could always use `dispatchEvent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$('#editor .toolbar .bold').click()`. It's not the Jedi way, but it works correctly.

*UPD*

After fast looking at wysiwyg sources I think that it's only correct way to do it.

*UPD*

And the right answer is `$('#editor-textarea').data('wysiwyg').triggerControl('bold',{});`

Comment: Hmmm... And first option with direct access?

Comment: try that `$('#editor-textarea').data('wysiwyg').triggerControl('bold',{});`

Comment: Yes, that worked!  Want to add that to your answer so I can accept it?